# Why is compactness needed for proving that Kahler forms are open

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am studying complex geometry from Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry - An Introduction*. In
Corollary 3.1.8 he proves that:

> The set of all Kahler forms on a compact complex manifold
>   $X$ is an open convex cone in the linear space 
>   $\{\omega\in \pmb{A}^{1,1}(X)\cap \pmb{A}^2(X)|d\omega = 0\}$.

In his proof:

(Writing $(h_{ij})>0$ as a short hand for $(h_{ij})$ is positive definite.)

> The positivity of an hermitian matrix $(h_{ij}(x))$ is an open property and,
>   since $X$ is compact, the set of forms $\omega\in \pmb{A}^{1,1}(X)\cap \pmb{A}^2(X)$
>   that are locally of the form 
>   $\omega = \frac{i}{2} \sum h_{ij} dz_i \wedge d\bar{z}_j$ with $(h_{ij})$ positive 
>   definite at every point is open.

But I am confused in where he used the property of compactness in the proof.
I thought that, if I could find a point $x\in X$ such that $(h_{ij}(x))>0$,
then I could find a small open neighbourhood around this point, in which $(h_{ij})>0$ for
every point in the neighbourhood. Then all the Kahler forms is a union of
such neighbourhoods, and is thus open. So no compactness is required.

I realize that I had been sloppy in my thought. So a counter example is also welcome!

---

Update: Solved in comments.

Comment: The set of forms which are positive in a chart is open. Since you can cover the manifold with finitely many charts (because it is compact) the set of forms which are everywhere positive is open.

Comment: That's where compactness is used.

Comment: Then why the finiteness of the number of charts is important? It is because of the particular topology given on the forms?

Comment: @taper No, it's much simpler than that... for every chart $U$, there's an open set of forms $V_U$ that are positive on $U$. If you have a collection of charts $U_i$, then the set of forms positive on all of the $U_i$ is the set $\bigcap_i V_{U_i}$...

Comment: The intersection of infinitely many open sets is in general not an open set.

Comment: Oh! I missed that I need to take intersection. Thank for pointing out! @MikeMiller & Mariano Suárez-Alvarez